# Converting java method to C#: converting bytes to integers with bit shift operators

Tags: c#, java, bit-manipulation

I am trying to convert the following 2 methods into c# without the .net compiler complaining at me.  Quite frankly I just don't understand how the two methods are really working behind the scenes.  So an answer and explanation would be great here.

```
public static int bytesToInt(byte b0, byte b1, byte b2, byte b3)
{
        return (((int)b0 << 24) & 0xFF000000)
            | (((int)b1 << 16) & 0x00FF0000)
            | (((int)b2 << 8) & 0x0000FF00)
            | ((int)b3 & 0x000000FF);
}

public static byte[] charToBytes(char c)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[2];

    result[0] = (byte) ((c >>> 8) & 0x00FF);
    result[1] = (byte) ((c >>> 0) & 0x00FF);

    return result;
}
```

The second method is particularly confusing because of the shift operator being used that is different that the first method.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ">>>" is the unsigned right shift operator in Java. It can be replaced with ">>", which, however, sign-extends the value if it's negative.  In this case, however, the use of the ">>" operator is harmless, since the result is reduced to a single byte in value (`& 0x00FF`).

The masking used in bytesToInt (`& 0xFF000000` and so on) was necessary in Java because in Java, bytes are signed values, that is, they can be positive or negative, and converting to `int` can sign-extend a negative value.  In C#, however, bytes can only be positive, so no masking is necessary.  Thus, the bytesToInt method can be rewritten simply as:

```
return (((int)b0 << 24))    
  | (((int)b1 << 16))
  | (((int)b2 << 8))
  | ((int)b3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class to do conversions between base data types and byte arrays.

Rewriting the `bytesToInt()` method would look like the following:

```
public static int BytesToIntUsingBitConverter(byte b0, byte b1, byte b2, byte b3)
{
  var byteArray = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? new byte[] { b3, b2, b1, b0 } : new byte[] { b0, b1, b2, b3 };

  return BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArray, 0);
}
```

And rewriting the `charToBytes()` method would look like the following:

```
public static byte[] CharToBytesUsingBitConverter(char c)
{
  byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(c);
  return BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? new byte[] { byteArray[1], byteArray[0] } : byteArray;
}
```

Comment: Eric,  Your answer is great as well as correct.  Thanks for the effort.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm a fan of letting the framework do as much of the work for me as I can. :)