# Convert byte to int using bitwise operators

Tags: java, type-conversion, integer, bit-manipulation, byte

I'm documenting some code in Java. The goal is to read and process an [OSRM file](http://project-osrm.org/) which is a file containing hex codes.

The flow is as follows: Read in some byte to a `ByteBuffer` using a `FileChannel`. Once the buffer is filled, convert every byte to a signed integer. This is done using the bitwise `&` operator and the signed left shift operator `<<`, and looks like this:

```
return  (0x000000ff & (bb.get() << 0)) |
        (0x0000ff00 & (bb.get() << 8)) |
        (0x00ff0000 & (bb.get() << 16)) |
        (0xff000000 & (bb.get() << 24));
```

Where `bb` is of course the `ByteBuffer`.

I have totally no clue how and why this code works, I Googled a bit and the closest thing I found was the following Stack Overflow question: [Converting Java method to C#: converting bytes to integers with bit shift operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920993/converting-java-method-to-c-converting-bytes-to-integers-with-bit-shift-operat).

Still, I have no clue and I'm wondering if someone could help me figure out this code snippet.

Comment: Much better to use ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer

Comment: This is not possible because the file also includes unsigned ints, booleans, ....

Comment: Then at least use ByteBuffer.getInt

Comment: The code is poor - it's reinventing the wheel and might as well use a simple array..  Just put 4 bytes in then call getInt().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This reads four bytes from the underlying byte buffer and stitches them together into an `int` value like this:

```
                        11111111 (first byte read)
                22222222         (second byte read)
        33333333                 (third byte read)
44444444                         (fourth byte read)
```

To achieve that, a bitwise OR operation is performed on all subresults, where each subresult prepares one row in the above diagram. For example, the third row is prepared as

```
(0x00ff0000 & (bb.get() << 16))
```

which does the following:

1. read the byte:

   ```
   xxxxxxxx
   ```
2. expand the `byte` into an `int`:

   ```
   000000000000000000000000xxxxxxxx
   ```
3. shift the bits to the left by 16 slots:

   ```
   00000000xxxxxxxx0000000000000000
   ```
4. finally, push this through an AND mask which lets only the `x` bits through. This is needed because `byte` is signed, so the conversion to `int` may actually result in the following:

   ```
   111111111111111111111111xxxxxxxx
   ```

The code would perhaps be simpler if a constant AND-mask was performed *before* shifting:

```
(bb.get() & 0xFF) << 16
```

This is actually the standard idiom for Java in these bit-twiddling operations.

---

Although not an answer to the question you have asked, using the provided API would certainly be preferred (the `getInt` method). Your byte order is little endian, so you would just need to set it up:

```
bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

For reference, this is the JDK's implementation of the same code:

```
static private int makeInt(byte b3, byte b2, byte b1, byte b0) {
    return (((b3       ) << 24) |
            ((b2 & 0xff) << 16) |
            ((b1 & 0xff) <<  8) |
            ((b0 & 0xff)      ));
}
```

Comment: Is there another way of doing so? and if so, does it lower the process speed?

Comment: You mean, in addition to the way recommended at the end of my answer and through the comments?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it reads in four bytes, each of which is eight bits and it combines them together into an integer which is 32 bits. It does this by shifting each successive byte an extra 8 places to the left, so the first byte read is placed into the last (lowest order) 8 bits of the integer (0-7); the next byte goes into the next 8 bits (15-8), etc.

It would be a lot easier to use the actual functionality of the ByteBuffer to do this though:

```
bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); // Called once on the buffer
int intFromNextFourBytes = bb.getInt(); // Read the same value as your code.
```